# How to move focus using up, down, left and right keys just like a datagrid in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, focus, tab-ordering

In my WPF application, I want to move focus to the controls using up, down, left and right keys.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you referring to the tab ordering? This means the order in which the focus cycles through your controls when you press TAB or SHIFT-TAB.

The tab ordering in WPF doesn't run in a specific sequence of numbers.  Rather, it just checks to see what hte next highest number is.  Ie:  you could set one control to 0 and one control to 45 and as long there aren't any controls between 0 and 45 then it will jump to 45.  To set the order in xaml you add this attached property to your definitions:

```
<Control KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="0" />
```

If you want to exclude controls from the tab order you can:

```
<control IsTabStop="false"/>
```

If you'd like to know more information or this doesn't apply to you then can you please supply more detail in your question?